# text to picture with mysql information

Tags: php, mysql

im building a website indianskincare.co.in which is coming out to what i want. the problem is i want to turn all text for each product into pictures as my client wants the text not to be so easily copied. i see how this is done using PHP by calling the PHP in the image source and the relevant code in the php.

it works on normal text wonderfully but when i include mysql row or any complex code it shows a broken image.

this works displays time and text

```
Header( "Content-type: image/png");


$image = imagecreate(320,130);
$date = date ("F dS Y h:i a");
$ip = "ip";
$fullip = "Your IP address is $ip.";
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0);
$red = ImageColorAllocate($image,204,0,0);
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255);
ImageFilledRectangle($image,0,0,320,130,$white);
ImageString($image, 14, 0, 0, "$fullip", $red);
ImageString($image, 12, 0, 24, "Time is $date", $black);
ImagePNG($image);
ImageDestroy($image);
```

I tried to add my mysql code between one of the variables (i didn't think it would matter between which) which works perfectly otherwise on another page but can't seem to change the text into picture.

mysql code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE id='$id'", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

                /* Fetching data from the field "title" */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
echo "<div style='overflow-x:hidden;width:20%;margin:0.5em;text-align:center;float:left;'>";
echo "<h3>".$row['name']."</h3>";
echo "<img  style='width:100%;margin:0;' src='".$row['image']."' /><br>";
echo "<h1><img style='height:4%;' src='images/rs.png' />".$row['price']."</h1><br><a href='product.php?cat=".$row['short']."'>Back</a><br>";
echo "</div><div style='width:50%;float:left;'>";
echo "<h5 style='font-weight:normal;'>".$row['description']."</h5><br>";
```

so my question is how to modify the text from mysql array into image.

ps: i know mysql is being deprecated not preferred but ive already done the website using this and i will not be able to modify it to use the other methods

Comment: it's heartening to know that someone can down-vote this without any comment as to why

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but is your client aware of all the issues that this will cause? You're going to have major issues with browser compatibility, you're going to ensure that no one who uses a screen reader can use your site at all, and maintaining the content will be that little bit more difficult. And someone sufficiently motivated can still grab the content with just a little extra work.

Comment: I did not downvoye (yet), but it was probably because you just showed two unconnected code blocks. Try showing the actual code you tried. However if you are echoing html then you are already onto a loser. Look at how the working image code works (hint - `ImageString` takes a string, and there is no echos) and go from there.

Comment: andrew. how will it cause all these problems when the text is all coming from database

Comment: steve. i don't know code at all. i only modify existing code with logic i can find online. i found the code above and tried to modify it. ill research the imagestring option

Comment: @SaudKazia - because your visitors will be looking at your generated images, regardless of where they're being generated from. You'll need to check that the image you're sending is the right size to fit in the user's browser, because it won't be able to move the contents around like it can with text (will you send the same size image to a desktop browser as you will to a mobile?)

Comment: You need to show us exactly how you're implementing that code. Do that in an edit to your question. Using a query as the text can be done.

Comment: andrew. fair point. well i guess its back to the drawing board. maybe use the no rightclick method *ugh* or similar. gonna delete this as it doesn't seem to be possible in a usable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a time ago I use this class - and it works perfectly:

http://image.intervention.io/

Intervention Image requires the following components to work correctly.

```
PHP >= 5.3
Fileinfo Extension
```

And one of the following image libraries.

```
GD Library (>=2.0) … or …
Imagick PHP extension (>=6.5.7)
```

A good start is to install the composer:
https://packagist.org/

With the composer you can easily install PHP Packages / Modules for almost all issue.
Example from the page (how to convert text to an image)

```
// create Image from file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// write text
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');

// write text at position
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

// use callback to define details
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('foo/bar.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('top');
    $font->angle(45);
});

// draw transparent text
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
});
```

So an example for your code could be (if intervention image class is working):

```
$result = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $result[] = array(
        'name' => convertToImage($row['name'], $row['id'].'_name'),
        'price' => convertToImage($row['price'], $row['id'].'_price')
    )
}

function convertToImage($text, $name) {
    $img = Image::make('images/transparent.png');
    $img->text($text);
    $img->save('images/'.$name.'.png');
    return '<img src="images/'.$name.'.png">';
}
?>
```

Comment: so how to incorporate the mysql. that i the main issue here

Comment: im gonna mark your answer correct but basically Andrew has given a reason not to do it. Thanks.